# Defining a JS function on a master page but modifying it with a content page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a JS function on a content page that requires some control IDs specific to that content page.

**Content Page**

```
 function invokeAjaxrequest() {
            $find("<%= RadAjax1.ClientID%>").ajaxRequestWithTarget("<%= RadAjax1.UniqueID%>", "reload");
        }
```

**Master Page**

```
function closeAlert(oWnd) {
            var arg = oWnd.argument;
            if (arg) {
                addAlert(arg);
                invokeAjaxrequest();
            }
        }
```

How can I define the invokeajaxrequest function, or check if it exists in the master page such that if a content page does not have it defined, it will not cause an exception?

Comment: how do you access your content page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

**Master Page** - Define default function behavior

```
<!-- this will be overridden in the content page -->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageScriptSection" >
    function invokeAjaxrequest() {
    }
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

That makes sure the function alwayss exist. To override it, you define it in the content page

**Content Page** - Override script for specific page if necessary

```
<asp:Content ID="CustomScript" ContentPlaceHolder="PageScriptSection">
    function invokeAjaxrequest() {
         $find("<%= RadAjax1.ClientID%>").ajaxRequestWithTarget("<%= RadAjax1.UniqueID%>", "reload");
    }
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: As long as the code in the master page is before the code in the content page (I forget with `ContentPlaceHolder`), this is an elegant solution.

Comment: I think this seems more elegant then @freedomn-m however both will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a function exists with

```
    if (typeof func === "function")
```

to add to your code:

```
    function closeAlert(oWnd) {
        var arg = oWnd.argument;
        if (arg) {
            addAlert(arg);
            if (typeof invokeAjaxrequest === "function") { 
                invokeAjaxrequest();
            }
            // misread - you _don't_ want an error if it doesn't exist
            // so just do nothing here (don't have the else)
            //else {
            //    alert("invokeAjaxrequest must be defined on each page");
            //}
        }
    }
```

As an extra, I would consider using some form of callback rather than checking if a func exists.

Answer (score 0):

All general functions are metods in window object.

Assuming that your content page is loaded in a parent iframe,

check from content window in parent (master):

```
if (window.parent.invokeAjaxrequest== "function") { }
```

define from content window in parent (master):

```
window.parent.invokeAjaxrequest = function() { .... };
```

please be careful with cross domain policy if you use such one, otherwise you will get an "protection" error and you woudn't be able to access nothing from parent to content vice verca.